# Find Coordinates of Collinear Point

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

**Hey, so I'm trying to get the coordinates Y of the third colinear point in javascript**

[image]

so like in this example we're trying to find the Y coordinate of P3.

I wrote a small code :

```
p1 = {
  x: -6,
  y: -9
}

p2 = {
  x: 3,
  y: -3
}


p3 = {            
  x: 12
}

a = p2.y - p1.y
b = p2.x - p1.x
slob = a/b

b = -(slob*p2.x - p2.y)

y = slob*p3.x + b

p3.y = y

console.log(p3)

// checks if its correct
var a = p1.x * (p2.y - p3.y) + p2.x * (p3.y - p1.y) + p3.x * (p1.y - p2.y);

if (a == 0){
  console.log("correct")
} else {

  console.log(a, 'incorrect')
}
```

But weirdly it only works for this concrete example.

**Does anybody has any ideas of how to do that or what am I doing wrong**

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the logged value of `a`?

Answer (score 0):

The key idea of the solution is that the ratio of the sides stays the same.
In other words,

```
(p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x)
```

... which is stored as `slob` in your code, should be equal to both:

```
(p3.y - p2.y) / (p3.x - p2.x) // shoulders
(p3.y - p1.y) / (p3.x - p1.x) // big triangle
```

Now, your code attempts to calculate the missing value (`p3.y`) based on the first of those. There's a lot of reassigning different values to the same variables (which is a bad practice btw), but in the end it boils down to this equation:

```
p3.y = slob * (p3.x - p2.x) + p2.y
```

... which is algebraically correct. Now, the checking expression uses 'big triangle' formula, which can be simplified to this:

```
p3.x * (p2.y - p1.y) = p1.x * (p2.y - p3.y) + p2.x * (p3.y - p1.y)
```

---

Your real problem here is that two approaches - the 'solution' one and the 'checker' one - are different in how they use floating-point math. The checking expression substracts and multiplies its operands, but there's never a case of division there.

It's not like that, however, with 'solution' approach. In the given example, `slob` is `6 / 9` - which means it can be stored only with a certain level of precision in JavaScript.

Now, sometimes you get lucky - and the stored value's precision is enough. But sometimes it's snake eyes, like [in this infamous example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken):

```
0.3 === 0.2 + 0.1 // false
```

... and you actually get *slightly* incorrect result stored in p3.y, which is enough to tip the scales of checker equation.